Какую модель выбрать для определение опорных точек на снимке с дрона? И как это сделать?
Передо мной стоит задача создать модель ИИ, которая определяет опорные точки на снимках с дрона (пример ниже). Мне не нужно точно определять, что это за объект, просто поставить над ним маркер и все. Я новичок в этом деле.
Как это можно сделать, какую модель выбрать? Желательно, чтобы работала быстро и не ресурсозатратно. Или может вообще есть какой-то готовый вариант этого, мне будет достаточно (надо на курсовую работу).
Может вообще есть алгоритмы для такой темы, тоже сойдет 
Вот ссылка на фотографии примеры: https://imgur.com/a/KFNIECn

Можно к примеру попытаться yolov8 обучить‍♀️

@Amgarak это понятно, но он будет же искать все объекты на снимке и пытаться их определить, а мне надо те, которые имеют отличительные свойства, именно на этом снимке

Соберите 5к таких фотографий, выделите на них интересующие зоны и возможно этого хватит для обучения.
